# Invalid syntax in lambda expression

Tags: python, lambda

I have a `list_of_lists`, with `inner_lists` that have string items.
I want to edit that lists using a lambda function, normalizing them in the same basis.

I'm using the following code:

```
for inner_list in list_of_lists:
    newlist=map(lambda x=float(x)/float(max(inner_list)),inner_list)
    return newlist
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
File "/Users/file.py", line 605
newlist=map(lambda x=float(x)/float(max(inner_list)),inner_list)
                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It seems like something pretty simple, but I already researched and couldn't find the damn reason!

Comment: That's not the correct lambda syntax. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the `=` in the lambda expression with a `:`.

```
newlist = map(lambda x: float(x)/float(max(inner_list)),inner_list)
```

You are not assigning a variable here, you are defining an anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

[Lambda expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) use colons, not assignment operators.